# Prevent comment spam with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to modify my htaccess to prevent the instance of spammers and found a tip over at Search Engine Journal that said to add this to my file:

```
# Protect from spam bots
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post\.php*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.yourwebsite.com.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) ^http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

---

My current file has the following code... how do I merge the two? Or should I not even bother adding the additional stuff? I appreciate your thoughts on this.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Virtually all spambots will get around that without any issues. Have you tried a proper spam fighting system like Akismet?

Comment: Yes, I have that installed, as well as two others. The article I referenced suggested a trio of plugins to be installed together- Akisment, AVH First Defense Against Spam Plugin and Growmap Anti Spambot Plugin. And also suggested the addition to the htaccess that I referenced as an added layer to perhaps block some of the spam bots. I admit it sounds like a lot, but the author claims to not have had a single spam comment make it through his wall of defense and to his blog. And, there's no cost to my site's speed or my wallet, so the question for me was, why not?